# Parsing using Java or Parsing using Oracle's parser

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing, informatica

I have XML files on file system (Unix/Windows) that I need to parse and populate a table with the required attributes. I have written a DOM parser on Java that takes XML as input and converts/parses into delimited files. I then populate the table by Informatica using indirect file load. The performance of this is pretty decent.
However, one of my seniors told me that converting into delimited files and then putting into a table is not required. Instead he asked me to put the XML files directly into a column of a table (preferably CLOB or XMLType) and then use Oracle's XML parser to parse the files. 

I do know that XML parsing is possible through Oracle's parser but is it recommended to have source files into a database table? This question is more from a design's perspective.
Appreciate your inputs on this.

Answer (score 1):

Storing XML in the database has several advantages.

1. **Less skills required.**  Few people in this world are an expert in Java *and* Informatica *and* Oracle.  An expert isn't always needed; but without one the solution will likely never be "great" and troubleshooting tough problems may be impossible.
2. **Less Conversion**  Errors usually happen at boundaries, and Java to text file to Informatica to Oracle has a lot of boundaries.  Are all of those tools setup to support internationalization?  Do they all agree on the date format?  Is there a byte order mark?  These issues are usually more complicated than people realize.
3. **Keep the XML nearby when it fails.**  Inevitably the input files will be corrupt and some ETL process will fail.  Then it's very convenient to have it all in one place.  (At least in my industry, where nobody would have permissions on both the application server and the database server.)
4. **Performance.**  High performance is the result of #1 and #2; being able to hire a single expert who can tune the system, and having fewer parts to worry about.  Lots of people can write code in Java, Informatica, and Oracle; how many of them can parallelize it?  Per [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law) parallelism will only significantly help if the entire process is parallelized.
5. **Ad hoc analysis with SQL XML features.**  Oracle has some useful declarative tools for writing ad hoc queries against XML.  Specifically the [XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions269.htm#SQLRF52054) feature is a great way to rapidly turn XML into a table.  If the XML is straight forward sometimes the entire work can be done in a single SQL statement, no need for any procedural code.